# How to have the same output for multiple different inputs in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a Discord bot from scratch and I want the same output to come from various inputs. The code that makes sense to me for this would be

```
import random
list = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
if message.content == ['random message', 'message random']:
        response = random.choice(list)
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

Both inputs, either "random message" or "message random" should work to get a random item from the list, but this code does not work. I haven't found any other documentation on this online, probably because it's obvious. Can anyone explain what the correct code would be?

-nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.content == ['random message', 'message random']` tests if `message.content` is exactly equal to that list, including order. What you want is the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).

```
if message.content in ['random message', 'message random']
```

This will be true if the message is either `"random message"` or `"message random"`. A faster implementation would be to convert the list of possible messages to a set. For two messages, it won't make a difference, but for longer lists, it is faster to test membership in a set.

```
if message.content in {'random message', 'message random'}
```

Comment: thank you! this has put me on the right track, but changing the code to this gives me the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment`. What does this mean?

Comment: it means you are trying to use `response` before you ever defined it

Comment: oh haha, turns out I had a misspelling. sorry for the trouble, thanks for your help !

Comment: no problem, if this answered your question, please select the green arrow to mark it as the answer